# identity value way off in a restored database

Tags: sql-server, backup, identity

I have a table with a identity primary key column. Its last value is 5228491220 using IDENT_CURRENT.

I make a full backup of the database, restore it on a second server. (We backup and restore daily from one server to the other one.) Immediately I pull IDENT_CURRENT from this table and the value is 5228501279.

That is, the restore jumps the last value by more than 10000.

I can't make sense of it. Why would the last value of this identity column not be carried properly through the backup?

More practically, how do I make sure the value carries over properly?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2012+, [this may explain it](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2014/06/17/lost-identity.aspx).

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik hits it - this is 100% by design. It really shouldn't matter, if you're OCD I'd suggest not using identity.

Comment: yep, you nailed it, this column is a bigint, exactly the gap we observe. You guys are good. thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

If you're on SQL Server 2012 (or newer), you may be running into a planned change, where [identity values are retrieved in batches, and the next ID value may be incremented after a shutdown](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2014/06/17/lost-identity.aspx), or a restore.

Quick summary: SQL grabs its IDENTITY values in batches, and if it's not sure what the last ID used was, it will increment the next IDENTITY value by 10 (for `tinyint`) to 10000 (for `bigint`) when starting back up.

(Compiled from comments)